# can't make bootstrap modal + codeigniter work together

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2

I have a bootstrap (2.3.2) modal defined as this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a button like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="index.php/mycontroller/methodname" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

method in controller:

```
public function methodname() {
      $this->load->view('modalbody');
}
```

If I directly use browser to access: localhost/myproject/index.php/mycontroller/methodname I can get the html without any problem, but if I click on the button, I got an 500 internal server error . Why and how to fix this?

**Edit:** when the modal is loaded I don't see my html got injected inside 'modal-body'. Also I digged a little deeper (by using firefox + firebug) and the internel error was 'The action you have requested is not allowed.' (when using google chrome it didn't show any detailed error msg) which has something to do with csrf_protection (I have set this to true). So which means when calling this modal, I have to pass the csrf token name and hash (ie. by using  $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();), but I have looked at the bootstrap js source code, data-remote is simply calling the jQuery load function:

```
.load(this.options.remote)
```

without accepting any data, so how am I going to pass the csrf token name and hash????

Comment: Get a 500 error where? In an inspector? Is whole page is a 500 error? Does the modal come up at all?

Comment: i have edited my question please see above

Comment: Can you include the code for both views? Or at least more detail on what you are trying to do. Using the code you posted here, I am unable to reproduce the issue. Even with CSRF turned on and forms both on the page and in the modal view.

Comment: @stormdrain I am curious of how you make this work without using get_csrf_token_name and it's hash. If you turn csrf on and use bootstrap modal (with remote setting to an internal link), it will call the jquery load function, so without passing csrf it will get the 500 internal server error: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/199318/#934067

Comment: I'm curious about *why* you would be submitting a form into a modal? That's the only thing CSRF should care about -- if you're submitting a form. I don't get how/why you would submit (e.g. `$_POST`) **into** a modal. Is it a result page or something?

Comment: I did not submit the modal as a form, (please see my code above) All I'm trying to do was to make the modal work with codeigniter. When I used firebug to debug I got the msg saying "The action you have requested is not allowed." which I looked at the codeigniter code and it has something to do with CSRF.

Comment: The thing is: CI's CSRF protection only cares about forms being submitted -- that's the only time it checks for tokens. I asked to see the rest of your code because here, locally, on a fresh CI install, with CSRF protection enabled, I do not get the same error. With more of your code, I may be able to reproduce the issue here to try an help diagnose the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, I knew why. I have the ajaxsetup definition (my pages has several ajax calls) with type: 'POST'. So when the modal calls the jquery load function, it takes the type value, and instead of using "get" it uses "post" so that's why my modal doesn't work without passing the CSRF. I have removed the 'type: POST' in ajaxsetup and now it's fine without passing any CSRF parameters.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it. StackO lesson learned: more code makes it easier to figure out what the problem is. Had you included that ajax in the original question, it would have been very easy to diagnose the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

try ../index.php... or ../../index.php... for modal url...

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks @stormdrain for pointing me to the right direction, here is why.

in my js file, I have the ajaxsetup definition (my pages has several ajax calls) with type: 'POST'. ie:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: 'index.php/page',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON'
    });
```

So when the modal calls the jquery load function, it takes the type value, and instead of using "get" it uses "post" so that's why my modal doesn't work without passing the CSRF. I have removed the 'type: POST' in ajaxsetup and now it's fine without passing any CSRF parameters